# FileInputStream to sql.Blob

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to upload an image to a database(sql.Blob), but I'm having problems converting objects.

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();

if (jf.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = jf.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] cadenaBytes =IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        imagenUser.setBytes(1, cadenaBytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

The problem is that when the last line is executed:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have a `FileInputStream` and I need a `sql.Blob`.

SOLUTION: Swap the last lane to:

```
imagenUser= new SerialBlob(cadenaBytes);
```

Comment: Where is the database-connection code?

Comment: I don't see `imagenUser` initialized -- is that the line from which you are seeing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: In other class. I am doing MVC and Mapper, this code are in Controller class.

Comment: Ok guys problem solved. The solution is swap the last line to               'imagenUser= new SerialBlob(cadenaBytes);'